# Gap on top and bottom when selecting button with jQuery

Tags: css, menu

I'm trying to change the background color of a button after hovering over it with jQuery. However, everytime I try I seem to be getting a gap on the top and bottom of each button rather than the whole button. Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5M2a/

HTML:

```
<div id="side-bar"> 
                <ul class="side-nav">
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                </ul>   
           </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#side-bar {
    float: left;
    width: 187px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.side-nav {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.menuOption {
    width: 187px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
div#side-bar ul li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Change your `-side-nav li` margin values (coming from the foundation stylesheet) to be padding and it should do what you want.

Comment: @m90, how do i do that?

Comment: You either change the original stylesheet or write your own rule overwriting that like `.sidenav li{margin: 0; padding: 4px 0 4px 0}` (values are placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the margin values for you li's. Currently foundation is giving them a margin-bottom of 0.4375em.

Add something like this to your CSS:

```
.side-bar li {
  margin-bottom:0:
}
```

UPDATE:

Working link here:

http://codepen.io/alexbaulch/pen/wKFvf